# Is it possible to generate new instances of the same form by clicking a button?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, .net-core

I'm working on a use case in my animal shelter web application where customers are able to register one or more animals at the same time. Ideally I'd like a button on the bottom left that generates another instance of the same form when clicked, so that multiple animal registrations can be saved to the database at once.

[image]

NewAnimalRegistration.cshtml:

```
@model NewAnimalRegistrationViewModel

<html>
<head>
    <title>Register an animal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container py-5">
    <div class=" row">
        <div class="col-md-10" mx-auto>
            <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
            <h1>Animal registration</h1>
            <p>
                We are happy to hear that you are interested in placing your animal in our shelter. Please fill in the fields below and our system will
                check if there is room for your animal.
            </p>
            <form asp-action="RegistrationForm" method="post">
                <div class="form-group row mt-5">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <label asp-for="Name">Name</label>
                        <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row mt-5">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <label asp-for="Gender" class="mr-3">Gender</label>
                        <select class="form-group" asp-for="Gender" asp-items="@ViewBag.Genders"></select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <label asp-for="Type" class="mr-3">Animal type</label>
                        <select class="form-group" asp-for="Type" asp-items="@ViewBag.AnimalTypes"></select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <label>Neutered</label>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input asp-for="IsNeutered" class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="true">
                            <label class="form-check-label" asp-for="IsNeutered">
                                Yes
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input asp-for="IsNeutered" class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="false">
                            <label class="form-check-label" asp-for="IsNeutered">
                                No
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mt-5">
                    <label asp-for="Reason">Why are you deciding to put this animal up for adoption?</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" asp-for="Reason" rows="6"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="float-right">
                    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-primary px-4">Cancel</a>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary px-4">Save</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to do this in .NET Core MVC? If yes, will I simply receive a list of all animal registrations through which I can simply loop and add them all to the database?

Comment: Hi @Vawkx, Is the problem solved? if my solution is helpful to you, you could mark it as answer, thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a demo based on your description, you can refer to it:

**Model:**

```
public class NewAnimalRegistrationViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public bool IsNeutered { get; set; }
    public string Reason { get; set; }

}
```

**Index.cshtml:**

```
@model NewAnimalRegistrationViewModel

<html>
<head>
    <title>Register an animal</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container py-5">
        <div class=" row">
            <div class="col-md-10" mx-auto>
                <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
                <h1>Animal registration</h1>
                <p>
                    We are happy to hear that you are interested in placing your animal in our shelter. Please fill in the fields below and our system will
                    check if there is room for your animal.
                </p>
                <form asp-action="RegistrationForm" method="post">
                

                    <div class="float-right">
                        <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-primary px-4">Cancel</a>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary px-4">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </form>

                <a id="add" href='#' class="text-danger">register another animal</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>

@section scripts{
    <script>
        var count = 0;
        $(function () {
            var actionUrl = "/Home/AddRegistrationForm?count=" + count;
            $.get(actionUrl).done(function (data) {
                $('body').find('.float-right').before(data);
            });
        })

        $("#add").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            count++;
            var actionUrl = "/Home/AddRegistrationForm?count=" + count;
            $.get(actionUrl).done(function (data) {
                $('body').find('.float-right').before(data);
            });
        })
    </script>

}
```

**_RegisterPartial.cshtml:**

```
@model NewAnimalRegistrationViewModel
@{ 
    int i = ViewBag.Count;

}

<h3>Anaimal @i</h3>

<div class="form-group row mt-5">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label asp-for="Name">Name</label>
        <input asp-for="Name" name="[@i].Name" class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row mt-5">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label asp-for="Gender" class="mr-3">Gender</label>
        <select class="form-group" asp-for="Gender" name="[@i].Gender" asp-items="@ViewBag.Genders"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label asp-for="Type" class="mr-3">Animal type</label>
        <select class="form-group" asp-for="Type" name="[@i].Type" asp-items="@ViewBag.AnimalTypes"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label>Neutered</label>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input asp-for="IsNeutered" name="[@i].IsNeutered"  class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="true">
            <label class="form-check-label" asp-for="IsNeutered">
                Yes
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input asp-for="IsNeutered" name="[@i].IsNeutered" class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="false">
            <label class="form-check-label" asp-for="IsNeutered">
                No
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group mt-5">
    <label asp-for="Reason">Why are you deciding to put this animal up for adoption?</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" asp-for="Reason" name="[@i].Reason" rows="6"></textarea>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult AddRegistrationForm(int count)
{
    ViewBag.Count = count;
    ViewBag.Genders = new List<SelectListItem> 
    { 
        new SelectListItem{ Text = "Female", Value="Female"},
        new SelectListItem{ Text = "Male", Value="Male"}
    };

    ViewBag.AnimalTypes = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem{ Text = "Cat", Value="Cat"},
        new SelectListItem{ Text = "Dog", Value="Dog"}
    };
    return PartialView("_RegisterPartial");
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult RegistrationForm(List<NewAnimalRegistrationViewModel> model)
{
    return View();
}
```

**Result:**

[image]